# Colocar uma url no campo text e mostrar ela em um DIV ao lado

Tags: javascript, html, html5, ajax

Como posso fazer isso? Tenho um formulário que tem alguns input text, gostaria que quando o usuário colasse uma url de uma imagem na web aparece ao lado um div com essa imagem. Creio que seria com Ajax mas não tenho nenhuma ideia de como começar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta criar o elemento com a URL da imagem:

```js
// SEM jQuery
// Executa a ação ao sair do campo, também pode usar `onkeyup`
// para ser executado tada vez que uma tecla é solta (mas não vejo necessidade)
document.getElementById('imagem').onblur = function(){
   // Pega o elemento onde será "impressa" a imagem
   var res = document.getElementById('result'); 

   // Cria o elemento img
   var img = document.createElement('img'); 

   // Atribui a URL como src
   img.setAttribute('src', this.value); 

   // Limpa o lugar de "impressão"
   res.innerHTML = ''; 

   // "Imprime" a imagem
   res.appendChild(img); 
}

// COM jQuery
// Executa evento ao sair do campo 'blur'
// Também pode usar 'keyup' para executar quando soltar a tecla
$(document).on('blur', '#imagem2', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // Pega o elemento de "impressão"
  $('#result').html(
    // Define o HTML dele como um novo element
    // img com src do valor do input
    $('<img />').attr('src', this.value)
  );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
SEM jQuery: <input type="url" id="imagem" /> <br>
COM jQuery: <input type="url" id="imagem2" /> <br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Kadu, muito obrigado!

Comment: Kadu, 
Nesse seu script teria como eu não apresentar a imagem tamanho real? Gostaria de apresentar uma imagem de 50 x 50 px

Comment: Tem sim, com jQuery você coloca assim `$('<img />').attr('src', this.value).css({'width': '50px', 'height': '50px')` sem faz assim: https://jsfiddle.net/tfx2op7p/1/

Comment: Kadu, deu certinho! Agora só preciso de mais 2 campos: Como posso pegar o que digitei no input text e exibir na div, o outro campo teria como pegar a data e hora atual e jogar em um input tbm?

Comment: @William a lógica é a mesma, só que você não vai precisar criar a tag `img` basta setar o valor da propriedade text assim `$(elemento).text( 'valor do texto' )`

Answer (score 2):

Então, para esse resultado não é necessário AJAX, uma vez que seu usuário vai colar uma URL de imagem da web. Se você colocar a url no atributo SRC do elemento html IMG assim que o usuário colar, você vai obter o resultado esperado.

Creio que seu maior problema vai ser validar se a url gerou uma imagem válida. Segue uma sugestão de código:

```js
window.changemeurlexample = function(e, el){  
  var resultimg = document.querySelector('#urlexampleresult');
  resultimg.setAttribute('src',el.value);
  document.querySelector('.str').innerHTML = el.value;
};
var resultimg = document.querySelector('#urlexampleresult');
resultimg.onerror = function(){
  alert('Imagem inválida.');
}
```

```css
.fleft{ float:left; }
.fright{ float: right; }
.fclear{ clear: both; }
.snippet #inputurl{padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #777;border-radius:2px;}
.result-image img{margin-left:20px;max-width: 200px;height:auto;display:block;min-width: 200px;height:200px;background-color:#eee;}
```

```html
<div class="snippet">
  <div class="fleft">
    <input onkeyup="window.changemeurlexample(event, this);" name="inputurl" id="inputurl" />
  </div>
  <div class="fright">
    <div class="result-image">
      <img src="" id="urlexampleresult" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="str"></div>
  <div class="fclear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

De uma maneira bem simples, e sem validacoes ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#btn_carrega_imagem').click(function(){
      $('#container_img').html('<img src="'+$("#url_imagem").val()+'" />');
      $('#container_img').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="url_imagem" id="url_imagem" value="http://www.palmeiras.com.br/public/upload/imagem/times//imagem_20_original.png" />
    <button id="btn_carrega_imagem">Carregar Imagem</button>
</form>

<div id="container_img">
    
</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado

Abraços

Answer (score 0):

Aproveitando o gancho da pergunta, exibiu tudo certo, porém eu gostaria de não apresentar a imagem no tamanho real, teria como usar alguma função ou propriedade para carregar no tamanho exemplo 50px x 50px ?